# How to make a JSON object parsed in Java class of JavaFX, be used/communicated/emitted to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, model-view-controller, plotly

I am parsing a JSON object in a java class of a GUI that I am creating in JavaFX. In order to display a plot in WebView, I created a HTML page within the Netbeans project and used  tag to add some javascript that can be used to create a plot in D3.js library in WebView.

How can I communicate between the java class containing the parsed JSON object and javascript present in the HTML file?

I have a controller class, xml document, html file to keep my logics separate.